Alternative to ngrx store subscription in the component?
in an application I am working on, I am creating a component that blocks the screen (overrides whatever screen there is) when a certain condition occurs.
I am using NgRx for state management.
private eventTypes = [
    'click',
    'mousedown',
    'mouseup',
    'keydown',
    'keyup',
    'keypress',
  ];
  private preventDefaultBound = (event: Event): void => this.preventDefault(event);


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showComponent$ = this.store.select(storeFeature.hasConnection);
    this.preventInteraction(); 
  }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
//This is not working as expected. After the component is destroyed, nothing is clickable
    this.allowInteraction(); 
  }

and I have some functions to prevent interaction and allow it again:
private preventInteraction(): void {
    this.eventTypes.forEach(eventType =>
      document.addEventListener(eventType, this.preventDefaultBound, true),
    );
  }

  private allowInteraction(): void {
    this.eventTypes.forEach(eventType =>
      document.removeEventListener(eventType, this.preventDefaultBound, true),
    );
  }

  private preventDefault(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

What I am trying to do is when the component is alive, the user can't press any button or perform any action in the application and when it is destroyed allow interaction.
This code works as expected:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showComponent$ = this.store.select(storeFeature.hasConnection);

    this.showComponent$.subscribe(show => {
      if (show) {
        this.preventInteraction();
      } else {
        this.allowInteraction();
      }
    });

But subscribing to the store directly is not recommended and I am trying to avoid it, is there an alternative to subscribing to the store while addressing this requirement?

You can get rid of all the complexity, by just using ngClass to add a class at the root of the HTML element, where you do not want HTML events to happen.
I am using async pipe to access the inner value, this will auto unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.
<div [ngClass]="showComponent$ | async ? 'no-dom-events' : ''">
    ....
</div>

Yes I am subscribing here, but what is the use of an observable without subscribing to it :)
Also the class will have the CSS pointer-events: none, which disables mouse interactions. You can specify this at the root styles file.
.no-dom-events {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}

